# PHP generic and dynamic form handling

Tags: php, database, forms

I'm in the need to write some PHP code to create and handle generic form inputs. This means an administrator from a backend should be able to create a list of forms, that have N fields of any type.
The users then will compile ONCE the different forms (for example one for could be user data and another for a questionnaire).

My idea is to create 3 separate tables as follows :

```
Table Forms
Form_ID
Form Name
Action
...

Table FormFieldsDescr
Field_ID
Form_ID
Label
Type
...

Table FormAnswers
Answer_ID  
User_ID
Field_ID
Value
...
```

This way the form and fields structure will be stored in the first two tables. In a separate table I'll store the single answers from the users, being able to reconstruct the whole structure at the moment of consulting the answers.

Is there a better way to store generic structured forms into a database?